# Algorithm to efficient compare items is a list pairwise

Tags: algorithm

I am looking for an efficient solution to the following problem:

Given 1 list L, with each one containing object R.

```
L = [R1, R2, R3, .., Rn]
```

Object R can be similar or not similar. This is determined
by a function is_similar(R1, R2) which returns True in case they are
similar and False otherwise.

The naive approach is to compare

```
R1-R2, R1-R3, ..., R1-Rn
R2-R3, R2-R4, ..., R2-Rn
...
```

I want to point that

```
if is_similar(R1, R2) and is_similar(R2, R3)
then is_similar(R1, R3) <=> True
but if is_similar(R1, R2) <=> is_similar(R2, R1)
```

Any know algorithm that can be used in this problem?

Comment: You could try a Bucket sort or sort then compare depending on the data type of each element.

Comment: In order to apply sort I need the less and equal operations. Am I correct?
I have only the equal operation (is_similar).

Comment: The naive approach is O(n^2), not n! ((n-1)+(n-2)+(n-3)...). If you can sort the list you can do  O(n log n), but you need a real comparator for that. Otherwise maybe you could use a union-find strategy ?

Comment: Is the "is_similar" a transitive relation, i.e. does is_similar(x,y) and is_similar(y,z) give is_similar(x,z)? In that case you could use an agglomerative clustering algorithm to merge the elements into sets of similar elements

Comment: Is is_similar an equivalence relation anyway ? If not I guess you'll never be able to do better than O(n^2)  (actually transitivity is enough to do better than that, but if yo have no property on is_similar you've basically lost)

Comment: @gdelab if we have 3 elements then we compare:
   R1-R2, R1-R3, R2-R3 -> 3! comparisons not 9 since we do not compare R2-R1, R3-R2, R3-R1 . Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes ;) That is 2+1+0=3=3*(3-1)/2 comparisons, not 3!=3*2*1=6

Comment: So in general (n-1)+(n-2)+...+1=n*(n-1)/2 = O(n^2). But with transitivity we should be able to do better.

Comment: I think I miss it but what is the problem?

Comment: Not sure you can do better in the worst case, i.e. when there are no similarities.

Comment: @PetarPetrovic I need to divide the List above to "groups" that all R objects in the group are similar.

Answer (score 3):

There are n(n-1)/2 possible comparisons between pairs of elements you can do.

Suppose you've performed all but one of these comparisons, and all comparisons so far have been false -- the single untested pair of elements may still be similar or not.

This shows that in the worst case one needs to check every possible pair of elements for equality, so there's no o(n^2) algorithm.

In general though, you can do better than comparing every pair of elements. Maintain a list of equivalence classes found so far, and only compare new elements to a representative from each.

Something like this in Python:

```
E = []
for i in items:
    for e in E:
        if is_similar(i, e[0]):
            e.append(i)
            break
    else:
        E.append([i])
```

After this code is executed, `E` will contain a list of equivalence classes of your items.

Comment: Thanks, already tried that but still the worst case does not improve as you suggested.

Comment: Unless you have more constraints on the input, if you're expecting a better-than-worst-case O(n^2) algorithm, then you're out of luck -- I proved in my answer that in the worst case n(n-1)/2 comparisons are needed.

Comment: Each object R has an attribute H, which can be used to 
compute distance(R1.H, R2.H) [integer].
If these R objects have small distance the is_similar function is much more probable to return True. In fact if distance is 0 then is_similar always returns True. Based on that maybe a probabilistic alforithm can be designed with a small error rate. I can live with a few errors but this complexity is killing me

Comment: @gosom You have to add this information to the question. I also have a hard time understanding how `distance` may play well with transitivity. The way how `is_similar` really works is crucial; you may want to spell it out explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

The naive algorithm is `(n-1)+(n-2)+...+1 = O(n^2)` in number of comparisons. You can't do better because without transitivity or ordering there is no way you can predict is_similar(Ri, Rj) without computing it, so you will have to compute it for each pair...

Comment: I am sorry, transitivity applies